# Adsense ads not showing up after multiple refreshing

Tags: javascript, ads, adsense

I have google ads, adsense on my website, but after testing the website throughout a lot refreshing suddenly the ads no longer show up. Why is that happening, and how would I fix it?

```
<script async src='//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js'></script>
<ins class='adsbygoogle' id = 'adClick'
     style='display:inline-block;width:100%;height:25%'
     data-ad-client='ca-pub-2820065049351531'
     data-ad-slot='4286171604'>
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: What browsers have you tested? Are there any reported errors in the console? Also, I hope that's not your actual client ID.

Comment: @TiesonT. You mean data-ad-client? You can view anyone's through the source code.